# Scrolling WebBrowser control on Windows phone 7

Tags: events, windows-phone-7, scroll, browser, webbrowser-control

I want to scroll down or up in the webbrowser control on the windows phone 7 using code behind (no javascript). i mean like using some button to scroll down for example. is that possible?

EDIT:
I tried to call a javascript function using InvokeScript, but it keeps giving me an unknown error 80020006. i tried to do this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.msn.com"));
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.InvokeScript("window.scrollBy(100,100);");
    }
```

something wrong in my code?

Comment: you can call a javascript function on your webbrowser from code behind. is that suitable for u?

Comment: i have'nt tried the javascript yet, i hoped theres a property or anything else to do that. in case theres no solution other than javascript, does anybody know how to do it? or even give me a link to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to interact with the scrolling of the page inside a WebBrowser control from outside of it.

In terms of doing it with JavaScript look at `windows.scrollBy()`

**update**

Try `webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "window.scrollBy(100,100);");`

But be aware that the page you're viewing may have overridden `eval` which coudl prevent this from running.

Note that the WebBrowser control was not intended to be used to view websites directly.
Also, have you tried calling `scrollBy` directly from within your own page?